# "The cohort were followed up at 2 months" or "The cohort was followed up at 2 months"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, past-tense, uncountable-nouns

Here, cohort is a group of 12-13 year olds.

Comment: You seem to have answered the question yourself. But next time, please include the question in the question. A title is to indicate the subject matter and a question should include, well, the question.

Answer (score -1):

Neither works, because you follow up 'with' a cohort. If you rewrite your sentence to say, "The researchers followed up with the cohort after two months."